# Cannot use ThreadPoolExecutor within threading.Thread (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, multithreading

Due to production needs, we updated our project to Python3.9. But the project stopped working because of `RuntimeError: can't register atexit after shutdown`, which did not occur with Python3.7. Our project has many threads and each thread might spawn sub-threads. We used `threading.Thread` for the higher levels and `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` at the bottom level. For example, the following code would work on 3.7 but not 3.9:

```
from threading import Thread
import concurrent.futures


def func1():
    print("func1 start")


def func2():
    print("func2 start")


def func3():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        print("func3 start")
        future1 = executor.submit(func1)
        future2 = executor.submit(func2)
        concurrent.futures.wait([future1, future2])
        print("func3 end")


thread1 = Thread(target=func1)
thread3 = Thread(target=func3)
thread1.start()
thread3.start()
thread1.join()
thread3.join()
```

with the following error in 3.9:

```
func1 start
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\my_project\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\my_project\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\my_projectr\tests\thread_test.py", line 13, in func2
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
  File "C:\my_project\lib\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 49, in __getattr__
    from .thread import ThreadPoolExecutor as te
  File "C:\my_project\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 37, in <module>
    threading._register_atexit(_python_exit)
  File "C:\my_project\lib\threading.py", line 1407, in _register_atexit
    raise RuntimeError("can't register atexit after shutdown")
RuntimeError: can't register atexit after shutdown
```

After some experimenting, I realized that ThreadPoolExecutor cannot be used under Thread while Thread can be used under ThreadPoolExecutor in Python3.9.

My questions are:

- Is this behaviour (change) intended? Why?
- What would be a proper way to use multi-level threading in Python3.9?

Comment: This example works for me on 3.9.5 on linux.

Comment: It acts as though the main thread has exited and started shutdown by the time the thread pool is started. You could wrap the main code in a generic try/finally with a print to see if there is something causing the main to exit unexpectedly.